# WSL, when logging in to bash, I have to type it twice for it to register my bashrc profile

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux, with ubuntu 16, when I go to my cmd line and type `bash` it logs in to bash:

[image]

typed bash

[image]

under my `mnt/c/Users/natec/bashrc$` I have in the file

```
~/.bashrc
```

But my profile isn't being loaded, so I have to type bash again for it to load, how can I make it load `~/.bashrc` by default?

Comment: My mistake, I meant ubuntu 16, I've updated OP.

Comment: What version of windows 10; Bash indicates your using a legacy WSL instance

Comment: version 17134..

Comment: This is the only one I've used, it did work, but all of a sudden it's doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem was with the `.profile` file:

The same problem has happened to me. After reinstalling the distro, I've ended up with a "refreshed" `.profile`, then made a comparison with a backed up copy. I've realized something interesting:

**The old `.profile`:**

```bsh
eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

**The new `.profile`**

```bsh
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

As you can see, there is a conditional at the new one that the old onde haven't :

```bsh
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

You could try to check your actual `.profile` and see if it's the case.

Answer (score -1):

seems like you're in the '/mnt' directory. This is for accessing windows files while using wsl. Try editing your .bashrc file in '/home/(username)' directory.